# Can I update a record if it exists, and insert it if not, for multiple rows in a single query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

For example we have this query in MySQL. Is there any way to write it in SQL Server?

```
INSERT INTO data (name, age, since, description) VALUES
     ("Bob", 23, "01-01-1980", "friend"),
     ("Bill", 33, "03-01-1980", "tall"),
     ("Jane", 43, "12-01-1980", "thin")
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE age=VALUES(age),
                         since=VALUES(since),
                         description=VALUES(description);
```

MERGE and IF Exists only work for single row insertion I think.

Comment: There is a 'boring's person' solution to this. Insert everything into a temp table, and then do 2 queries, one with insert into where bla bla not exists , and then update where join bla bla.. As I said that's a scenario when data is not BIG. Otherwise if a professional sees that,he /she will kill me.

Comment: MERGE works for any number of rows

Comment: @Nissus on the contrary, the UPDATE/INSERT (otherwise you end up updating what you inserted) is better for lots of data. MERGE isn't atomic, so you need an explicit transaction.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So you believe it's faster? I really thought that was a bad plan but a working one. You are right first update then insert.

Comment: Check Aaron Bertrand's [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). It's not just performance

Comment: MERGE can (and usually is in my experience) SET based.  But yes, Please read the Bertrand' article.  Sometimes it is better to fall back on INSERT/NOT-EXISTS and UPDATE/EXISTS ..  Pana.Kanavos' warnings are ON TARGET, please heed them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
merge data as target
    using (select v.*
           from (values ('Bob', 23, '1980-01-01', 'friend'),
                        ('Bill', 33, '1980-03-01', 'tall'),
                        ('Jane', 43, '1980-12-01', 'thin')
                ) v(name, age, since, description)
          ) as source
    on target.name = source.name
when matched
    update set age = source.age,
               since = source.since,
               description = source.description
where not matched then
    insert (name, age, since, description)
        values (source.name, source.age, source.since, source.description);
```

Note that you should always use single quotes for strings in all databases.  That is the SQL standard.

I also fixed the format of what looks like a date to be the standard YYYY-MM-DD format.  SQL Server actually prefers YYYYMMDD, but I like the hyphens (because they are ISO 8601 standard and more accepted across databases) and they almost always work in SQL Server.

Comment: `yyyyMMdd` would be better, due to how SQL Server handles the older data types.